# Broken link on heroku.com: hoster does not answer

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a link on this page:

https://infinite-taiga-25466.herokuapp.com/

Redirecting to this site:

https://www.bsi.bund.de/DE/Presse/Pressemitteilungen/Presse2018/Spectre-NG_18052018.html

But the hoster shows an error! When I copy the URL to the browsers address line, then everything works.

I want to address the topic to the hoster, but heroku.com redirects me here!

[image: hoster_error]

Comment: UPDATE: I contacted the `bsi.bund.de` and they told me that the web application firewall blocks my website. I was redirected to the hoster `bva.bund.de` but got no answer still!

Comment: Telephony central of `bva.bund.de` redirected me here: `https://www.itzbund.de/DE/Home/home_node.html`... better luck next time!

Comment: BTW: anybody from heroku.com here???